# Passing arguments change stats in drawRect method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos, ipad

I've got a problem with passing arguments to my drawRect methode.
It changes my given arguments in the method.

When I set the rectangle frame in drawRect directly it works fine, so there must be something wrong
with passing the arguments.

e.g. it changes 
So my Code is this.

ServiceAppViewController.m

```
-(void) initTransformBoxes{
TransformBox *transform = [[TransformBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, _transformArrowView.frame.origin.y+65,                                                                      _transformArrowView.frame.size.width,120)];

[transform setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

[transform drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[self.view addSubview:transform];


}

}
```

TransformBox.m

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

//but when I do it hard wired it works?
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);
CGContextAddRect(context,rectangle);
//instead of this
//    CGContextAddRect(context,rect);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Another question is, if I can make a static drawRect Method?
I've tried to override drawRect in the .h file but it was never called ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `[transform drawRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];`

The `drawRect:` method is called automatically when the view becomes visible, and the `rect` parameter is actually the frame of the view.

If you want to pass a parameter to your view to be drawn, pass it as a property to your `TransformBox` view.

When you need to change it (after you add it to the parent view) you use

```
[transform setSmallRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
[transform setNeedsDisplay];
```

and the drawRect will automatically get called. Use that property inside your drawRect method.

ServiceAppViewController.m

```
-(void) initTransformBoxes
{
    TransformBox *transform = [[TransformBox alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, _transformArrowView.frame.origin.y + 65,                                                                      _transformArrowView.frame.size.width, 120)];

    [transform setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

    [transform setSmallRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    [self.view addSubview:transform];
}
```

The `drawRect:` will be called after the view is added.

TransformBox.m

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    CGRect rectangle = [self smallRect];
    CGContextAddRect(context,rectangle);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```